# Type mismatch: cannot convert from activity to fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I'm working on tabs, but i m getting an error which says type mismatch: cannot convert from ExpenseEntry to fragment. i m having different activities which extends fragment class, but still it is showing error. i'm new at this and i don't know what next??

here is my code.

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {


    switch(arg0){
    case 0:

        return new ExpenseEntry();

        break;
    case 1:

        return new IncomeEntry();
        break;
    case 2:

        return new BudgetFix();

        break;
    }
    return null;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}





@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) public class ExpenseEntry extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expense_entry,container,false);

    return rootView;
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your imports are same you must have conflicting imports 
use either

- import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

or

- import android.app.Fragment;